# iPhone has no drivers in Windows 10

Tags: iphone, windows, driver

I can't browse my iphone 5 (10.2.1) in windows 10 explorer, it doesn't show up as a volume.

- The iphone is listed in the device manager, with a warning that it
  has no installed drivers.
- Windows cannot find any drivers online
  ("iPhone has no driver"), nor in Apple's common program files
  (`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support`).
- I've
  uninstalled and reinstalled itunes, and the Apple mobile device USB drivers, as a precaution. Iphone is still listed as driverless in
  device manager.
- I've installed the stand-alone Windows update
  (KB3099229_x64) containing media features that were excluded in my version of Windows 10 Pro N.
- I've unlocked my device.
- I've trusted the computer.
- I've rebooted the device.
- I've used three different USB ports.
- Windows and iphone is updated.
- Itunes can interface with the device with no problems.
- **Update:** There are no hardware problems. Everything works on a Windows 7 computer.

So, why don't there exist any drivers for iphone 5 for Windows 10? Seems like a rather huge oversight.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @Mark To access photos as a USB camera

Comment: What OS is on the iPhone 5? (+1 for the detailed list of things you have tried. Hopefully there's a solution other than use iCloud or another sync method. Even if it's an open source library and bash/unix support on Windows)

Comment: @bmike I updated the question (iOS 10.2.1). I have a hard time even figuring out if it's the cable's fault; iTunes can play back music from the phone and list all contents on it, Ubuntu can mount it (but lists no content — not sure if that is a definite sign of hardware error), it charges the battery ok, and the device is visible to Windows device manager...

Answer (score 1):

You should try [iExplorer for macOS and Windows.](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer) At $40 it is a bit pricy, but it is a virtual Swiss Army knife of an app for iOS devices. Worth every penny.

(Disclaimer: I'm a very satisfied user of iExplorer for macOS. No financial ties between me and Macroplant LLC.)

Comment: $40 sounds like current market value for my phone

Comment: Macroplant has a free demo trial, I believe. Download it and see if it does what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I might check it out if I need a workaround, but the same moment I accept not having drivers for the iPhone is the moment I no longer use iPhone :-)

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://www.copytrans.net/blog/solved-computer-and-itunes-not-recognizing-iphone-all-you-need-to-know-to-get-it-fixed/) I found in the Google universe. :-) Perhaps there is something you haven't tried yet. The site has an available app that downloads just the Windows <> iOS drivers.